# DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at node_modules\postcss\package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Since I upgraded Node to version 16, I started noticing this when I build my Angular app.

```
DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at "...\node_modules\postcss\package.json".

Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
```

Is there a way to fix this without downgrading the Node version?

Comment: Given that it's telling you the problem is in `postcss`: update the `postcss` dependency to something newer?

Answer (score 6):

Solution:

1. Go to defined location `C:\<xampp>\htdocs\<projName>\node_modules\tslib\package.json`.
2. At exports field - replace this `"./": "./"` to `"./": "./*"`.

Comment: With this solution, you would need to do that everytime you clone the repository or even upgrade the package... Please do not do this unless it is a temporary fix.

Comment: I don't even have an EXPORTS section and I get the error also.

Comment: I had to update it to "./*": "./*" .. just search for "./" and do the replacements.

Answer (score 6):

I was using node 16 switched back to 14 and it started working.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the GitHub issue, this one is recurrent one:

https://github.com/postcss/postcss/issues/1455#issuecomment-872240742

An update of `postcss` should do the job.

Comment: Recreate the lock file and do `` yarn upgrade @nuxt/postcss8``  should also do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your client directory in your project and `npm i postcss`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your package.json and check if you have `--prod` flag in the build script, if so update it for
`--configuration production`

That will solve the issue, too

Answer (score 1):

I suffered from the same issue but into tslib package
I tried updating version by version till this version 2.4.0
now everything works correctly

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this is to downgrade to a lower version of Node. But not doing a reinstall of Node.

Install NVM - Node version manager. That way you can have multiple versions of Node at the same time. For each project, you will be able to switch to a specific Node version you want. It can be found at https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

Go to node_modules\postcss\package.json

swap out "./": "./" with "./*": "./"

Comment: This is not a definitive solution : after an update, you will lose this update.